# Query dated expenses, aggregate and sum by months and by cagetories

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to extent Google sheets annual budget template.

I'd like to its Expenses sheet to pull and fill data from my detailed "Expense Breakdown" sheet automatically to avoid me filling the data twice.

Here is my table I need to fill in(there are many tables like that)
[image]

Here is my detailed expenses list
[image]

And here is a test spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rk03JI6-JRkaH5eixWJaOU5xwcOl2sVE_fMInOIBZhA/edit?usp=sharing

I tried pivot tables to aggregate dates into month and sum expenses, but for some reason, Google doesn't know how to do it.
So the way I see it, I need to place a formula into each cell in D46 to O53 range, where each cell will query expenses list, aggregate data(sum by category and date) there, then match and pull by date(from D2:O2 cella)and category (in C col). Does that make sense?

Can somebody help me to create a formula for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you need to fix your logic... every category (column A) needs to have unique sub-category (column C) meaning you cant have sub-category called `Other` for every category because you would output exact same values of `Other` sub-category for all categories

then use in D46, D4, D15, D24, etc...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 3)&":"&ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH("Monthly totals:", 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 3)&":C"), 0)+ROW()-4, ROWS(A:A)), 3)), 
 QUERY({'Expenses Breakdown'!B:F; {VALUE(TEXT(SEQUENCE(12, 1, 0, 29), "m/d/yyy")), 
 SEQUENCE(12, 3, 0, 0)&"♀", SEQUENCE(12, 1, 0, 0)}}, 
 "select Col3,sum(Col5) 
  where Col3 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "0♀", 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 3)&":"&ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH("Monthly totals:", 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 3)&":C"), 0)+ROW()-4, ROWS(A:A)), 3)))&"' 
 group by Col3 
 pivot month(Col1)+1"), COLUMN(B:M), 0)))
```

[image]

also, you may want to disable rounding:

[image]

---

for non-english sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); 3)&":"&ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH("Monthly totals:"; 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); 3)&":C"); 0)+ROW()-4; ROWS(A:A)); 3)); 
 QUERY({'Expenses Breakdown'!B:F; {VALUE(TEXT(SEQUENCE(12; 1; 0; 29); "m/d/yyy"))\ 
 SEQUENCE(12; 3; 0; 0)&"♀"\ SEQUENCE(12; 1; 0; 0)}}; 
 "select Col3,sum(Col5) 
  where Col3 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; "0♀"; 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); 3)&":"&ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH("Monthly totals:"; 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); 3)&":C"); 0)+ROW()-4; ROWS(A:A)); 3)))&"' 
 group by Col3 
 pivot month(Col1)+1"); COLUMN(B:M); 0)))
```

Comment: This is mind-blowing, It doesn't cease to amaze me how you hack these things out. Thank you it works. And I agree about others, in my main spreadsheet, I removed them.

Comment: What are those female signs for?

Comment: @AlexReds just a unique symbol for query's pivot because without it you wouldnt get monthly distribution for months which are not in Expenses Breakdown sheet. you can use any symbol you wish ♀♂♪♫♥☼►♫♣♠♦...

Comment: Do you mind explaining your code piece by piece? I liked the way the file is structured, the code is very well done, I want to adapt it to what I have but I'm having problems. I'm a newbie to Sheets and I can't see what's wrong. My file is in Portuguese, we use semicolons instead of commas in formulas. I don't know if the problem is in the date or currency format or other situations. My subcategories are all like this "[E] Família → Saúde". I used IFERROR for the QUERY and the error are now like this: "VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range".

Comment: @mykahveli try the 2nd formula from updated answer where comas and semicolons are properly translated for non-english sheets